# How do I assign mutliple cores to calculate the results of my user defined function?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I wrote a user defined function with eight different variables. I now want to change one of these variables 10 times while the others stay as they are AND assign multiple cores to the calculation to let it run faster.

I played around with the parallel package and also tried foreach but I seem to be doing something wrong syntax-wise.

```
my_function<-function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h){
   *do somehting with the input parameters*
}

values_for_a<-1:10
```

values b-h are set and won't change. Now here is what I tried with package parallel:

```
#assigning 6 cores for the calculations
no_cores <- detectCores() - 2
# Initiate cluster
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

result<-parLapply(cl, values_for_a, fun = my_function, b = 1, c = 2, d = 3, e = 4, f = 5, g = 6, h = 7)

stopCluster(cl)
```

I get an error message telling me, that an object which is used in the function can't get found. I can't explain why because I load this object. It IS in my library and if I use the function manually for one a value it works without a problem.

Can anybody help or does anybody have an alternative way of how I can parallelise my calculations?

Comment: I think in order to give you an informed answer- it is necessary to know what is in `a`, `b`... etc. just to have some context of how best to help you.

Also maybe try to start simple with `mclapply` and accomplish what you want with just `a` - then focus on `b`, `c` etc. 

eg. `my_function<-function(input){...process input...}; mclapply(a,my_function,mc.cores=10)` . 

Then maybe after that you could do something like: `for(i in list('a','b',....)){if(i=='a'){cores=10}else{cores=1}; input=get(paste0(i)); mclapply(input,my_function,mc.cores=cores)}`

Comment: another option is to use the `furrr` package which utilises the `future` archi. If you can write a function in the `lapply`/`purrr` syntax just use `furr::future_map` and it will parallelise for you.

Comment: What's your operating system?